# Extract object from middle of large text

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction

I am writing compiler for my new js framework , I am trying to extract object tree from my code directly. This is process which I will be doing in compilation (build) process so every code is considered as pure string.

```
     var a = 'Oxo('Storename',{templates:function(){},data:{},actions: 
      {}})'
```

I have my main code in format string in variable a . This string is passed to function **extraceObject()** now **extractObject** function will return me array which contain **StoreName** as 0 index and index 1 return me object as :-

```
        {
          templates:function(){},
          data:{},
          actions:{},
        }
```

template , data and action property contain large code .

I tried my best but I was not able to solve this problem because there are multiple numbers of closing **}** .

My code :-

```
HeavyExtraction = function HeavyExtraction(x) {
     var alldata = x,
         mydata  = x,
         len     = mydata.length;
     var  p1 ,
          p2 , 
          p = 0;
     for(var j = p ; j < len ; j++){
        if(mydata.indexOf("Oxo('") !== -1 ){
            var p1 = mydata.indexOf("Oxo('");
            var p2 = mydata.indexOf('})');
        }
        if(p1 == -1 || p2 == -1){
           console.log('syntax error') 
           break;
        }

        var str = mydata.substr(p1+6,(p2 -p1)-6).replace(/\\n/g, ''),
        var Data = mydata.substr(p1+6,(p2 -p1)-6);
        console.log(Data)
        var p = p2 + 2,
        mydata = mydata.substr(p),
        len = mydata.length;
   }
 }
```

I am trying to get output as :-

```
        ['Storename',{
         templates:function(){},
         data:{},
         actions:{},
        }]
```

I am trying to do this with node.js
Sorry For my worst code please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little while puzzling over this and came up with the following.
(The value of `templates` will be the function expression as a string, and if your `Storename` actually has quotes around it, the quotes would need to be removed.)

```
  const str = 'Oxo(Storename,{templates:function(){},data:{},actions:{}})';
  const storeName = str.substring(str.indexOf("(") + 1, str.indexOf(","))
  const iBeginObject = str.indexOf("{"), iEndObject = str.length - str.split("").reverse().join("").indexOf("}");
  const sObject = str.substring(iBeginObject, iEndObject)
      .split(/templates:/).join('"templates":"')
      .split(/,data:/).join('","data":')
      .split(/,actions:/).join(',"actions":');
  const arr = [storeName, JSON.parse(sObject)];
  console.log(arr);
```

The biggest caveat is that this code assumes the `data` and `actions` objects are JSON-formatted. I don't have the expertise to write a function that converts an arbitrary javascript object to JSON format in a reasonable amount of time, but this seems like a good [related resource](https://medium.com/the-n00b-code-chronicles/a-n00ber-pattern-for-taming-the-wild-data-web-da10e81a035c) that might make that unnecessary. (And I think there must be libraries that handle "JSONifying" objects since it's not an uncommon task, although I've never used one myself.)